# How would I parse a text file like this and edit it

Tags: vb.net, file, parsing, text, edit

Basically I want it to put show the separate data in textboxes.
When the textbox is edited it is edited in the text file too.
Is it possible to do this in vb.net?
If so what methods should I use?
The text file is formatted like this:

```
[1]
Name=Bulbasaur
InternalName=BULBASAUR
Type1=GRASS
Type2=POISON
BaseStats=45,49,49,45,65,65
GenderRate=FemaleOneEighth
GrowthRate=Parabolic
BaseEXP=64
EffortPoints=0,0,0,0,1,0
Rareness=45
Happiness=70
Abilities=OVERGROW
HiddenAbility=CHLOROPHYLL
Moves=1,TACKLE,3,GROWL,7,LEECHSEED,9,VINEWHIP,13,POISONPOWDER,13,SLEEPPOWDER,15,TAKEDOWN,19,RAZORLEAF,21,SWEETSCENT,25,GROWTH,27,DOUBLEEDGE,31,WORRYSEED,33,SYNTHESIS,37,SEEDBOMB
EggMoves=AMNESIA,CHARM,CURSE,ENDURE,GIGADRAIN,GRASSWHISTLE,INGRAIN,LEAFSTORM,MAGICALLEAF,NATUREPOWER,PETALDANCE,POWERWHIP,SKULLBASH,SLUDGE
Compatibility=1,7
StepsToHatch=5355
Height=0.7
Weight=6.9
Color=Green
Habitat=Grassland
Kind=Seed
Pokedex=Bulbasaur can be seen napping in bright sunlight. There is a seed on its back. By soaking up the sun's rays, the seed grows progressively larger.
BattlerPlayerY=0
BattlerEnemyY=25
BattlerAltitude=0
Evolutions=IVYSAUR,Level,16
[2]
Name=Ivysaur
InternalName=IVYSAUR
Type1=GRASS
Type2=POISON
BaseStats=60,62,63,60,80,80
GenderRate=FemaleOneEighth
GrowthRate=Parabolic
BaseEXP=141
EffortPoints=0,0,0,0,1,1
Rareness=45
Happiness=70
Abilities=OVERGROW
HiddenAbility=CHLOROPHYLL
Moves=1,TACKLE,1,GROWL,1,LEECHSEED,3,GROWL,7,LEECHSEED,9,VINEWHIP,13,POISONPOWDER,13,SLEEPPOWDER,15,TAKEDOWN,20,RAZORLEAF,23,SWEETSCENT,28,GROWTH,31,DOUBLEEDGE,36,WORRYSEED,39,SYNTHESIS,44,SOLARBEAM
EggMoves=
Compatibility=1,7
StepsToHatch=5355
Height=1.0
Weight=13.0
Color=Green
Habitat=Grassland
Kind=Seed
Pokedex=To support its bulb, Ivysaur's legs grow sturdy. If it spends more time lying in the sunlight, the bud will soon bloom into a large flower.
BattlerPlayerY=0
BattlerEnemyY=21
BattlerAltitude=0
Evolutions=VENUSAUR,Level,32
```

Comment: With as much data as you are storing for each entry (Pokemon), you should consider using a database for this kind of project.

Comment: Or at least an XML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an INI file.  In which case you can use the INI parser built into windows.  See [GetPrivateProfileString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ([pinvoke sig](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getprivateprofilestring)) and [WritePrivateProfileString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725501%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ([pinvoke sig](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/WritePrivateProfileString.html))